# How to mark only one row as "active" in a group shared same Id with particular conditions

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 like this:

[image: sample table]

Now I want to add one more column named "Status" to label each rows for same person.

- If Category = 3 and Fee <> 0 then label this row as "Active" and rest of them (1 and 2) would be "non-active";
- If Category = 3 and Fee = 0 then it move to Category = 1 where Fee <> 0 and make it as "Active", then rest of them(2, 3) would be "non-active" ;
- If Category = 3 and 1 and both Fee =0 , then mark the last one(Category =2) as "Active", no matter Fee of Category 2 = 0 / <> 0 .

I am thinking to use :

```
Status = CASE 
            WHEN (Category = 3 AND Fee <> 0 )
                 OR (Category = 3 AND Fee = 0 AND (Category = 1 AND Fee <> 0))  
                 OR (Category IN (1, 3) AND Fee = 0 AND (Category = 2 AND Fee IS NOT NULL)) 
               THEN "Active"
               ELSE "Non-Active"
         END
```

But I am not sure it is correct or not. And I am also wondering if there is more efficient way to achieve this outcome.

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: The expected result is listed as three points already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by personid
                                         order by (case when category = 3 and fee <> 0 then 1
                                                        when category = 1 and fee <> 0 then 2
                                                        when category = 2 then 3
                                                   else 4 end)
             then 'active' else 'inactive'
        end) as status
from t;
```

Comment: Great! I got the expected result. Thanks much!